# System interacting with Fermi Gas

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, fermions

My question denoted by a reduced dynamic for a system interacting with a reservoir.

Before asking the question, for completeness I will write in detail the statement of the problem and notation.

Consider a quantum system with the Hamiltonian $H_s$ interacting with Fermi gas. General Hamiltonian is
$$
H = H_s \otimes I_r + I_s \otimes H_r + V = H_0 + V,
$$
where $H_r, I_r$ are Hamiltonian and identity operator in the space of reservoir (Fermi gas, Fock space). $V$ is operator of the interaction of the system and the reservoir. In general $V = Q \otimes F$, where $Q, F$ are some operators in system's and reservoir's spaces.

Let $a(t)$ is operator of free evolution (without interacting) of system plus reservoir. For any observable $X$ in tensor product of system's and reservoir's spaces $a(t)X$ is solution of von Neumann equation
$$
\frac{dX}{dt} = -i [H_0, X],
$$
let Planck's constant $h=1$. So
$$
a(t)X = e^{-i H_0 t} X e^{i H_0 t}.
$$
With using Dyson approach we can derive solution of von Neumann equation with  interaction
$$
\frac{dU}{dt} = -i [H_0+V, U].
$$
Dyson series defined by operator $A(t)$
$$
A(T)U = a(t) \left( U + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-i)^k \int_{\Delta_k (t)} d t_1 \dots d t_k G(t_1) \dots G(t_k) U  \right),
$$
where $G(t)$ is operator, denoted by $G(t)U = [ a^{-1}(t)(V), U ]$, $\Delta_k(t) =\{ (t_1, \dots t_k) \in R^k: t \geq t_1 \geq t_2 \geq \dots \geq t_k \geq 0  \}$.

The initial state defined by operator $\omega = \omega_{\rho_0} \otimes \omega_{\beta, \mu}$. $\omega_{\rho_0} (X) = tr(X \rho_0)$ for any observable X in space of system, $\omega_{\beta, \mu}$ is KMS state.

And finally reduced dynamic of system $T_t: \rho_0 \to \rho(t) $ implicity denoted by relationship:
$$
tr(X T_t \rho_0) = \omega \left( A(t) \left( X \otimes I_r \right) \right).
$$

Typically, this formulation considers the transition to the limit of weak coupling or low density.  But I'm interested in how the observable $X \otimes I_r$ is related to the initial state $\omega$. More specifically, how does operator $A(t)$ change the observable $X \otimes I_r$. So $[H_s \otimes I_r, I_r \otimes H_r] = 0$, that
$$
e^{\alpha H_0} = e^{\alpha (H_s \otimes I_r) } e^{ \alpha(I_s \otimes H_r)} = e^{ \alpha(I_s \otimes H_r)} e^{\alpha (H_s \otimes I_r) }, \forall \alpha \in C
$$
Using the last formula we get $a^{-1}(t)V = a^{-1}(t) \left( Q \otimes F \right) = \left(a_s^{-1}(t) Q \right) \otimes \left( a_r^{-1}(t) F \right)$, where $a_s(t) X = e^{-i H_s t} X e^{i H_s t} $, $a_r(t) Y = e^{-i H_r t} Y e^{i H_r t} $. Finally, we get
$$
G(T) \left( X \otimes I_r \right) = [ a(t)V, X \otimes I_r ] = [ a_s(t)Q, X ] \otimes 0.
$$
The last formula is very strange, we get that initial state of reservoir doesn't influence to dynamic due to the last formula because we have $0$ everywhere for reservoir after applied Dyson series.

Where did I make a mistake? Or maybe I don't understand the problem statement correctly?